# Run exe form another exe and pass parameters

Tags: c++, automated-tests, dosbox

I am trying to make a program that calls another .exe and pass parameters to it. My case is to create a program to open two (dosbox.exe) and pass commands to it to run executables. I am trying to automate the testing process. 
I have tried code like this

```
ShellExecute(NULL, "open", "C:\chat\DOSBox 0.74.lnk.exe", NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWDEFAULT);
```

But it didn't even work. Any help?

Comment: removed assembly tag

Comment: Yeah, sorry for the confusion, I used the assembly tag cause I am using dosbox to run code written in assemblyx86, but obliviously the question has nothing to do with assembly. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about: `std::system( "dosbox -c myCommand" );` (assuming `dosbox.exe` and your custom `myCommand.exe` are in your path)?

To start two in the background, do:

```
std::system( "start dosbox -c myCommand1" );
std::system( "start dosbox -c myCommand2" );
// Program has launched these in the background
// and continues execution here.
```

Alternately, you could spin up a thread for each `std::system()` call:

```
auto cmd1 = std::async( [] { std::system( "dosbox -c myCommand1" ); } );
auto cmd2 = std::async( [] { std::system( "dosbox -c myCommand2" ); } );
// Program is launching these in the background
// and continues execution here.
```

You may also want to check the return value for each `std::system()` call to make sure it succeeded.

---

*Update*: You ask how to run two commands in the foreground in a single dosbox, which is located in another folder. You can embed the full path like this:

```
std::system( "c:\\MyDosBox\\dosbox.exe -c c:\\My\\Progams\\myCommand1.exe p1 p2 && c:\\Other\\myCommand2.exe p3 p4" );`
```

Comment: Let's say that I will run the c++ code using visual studio for example, and the dosbox.exe is located in another directory. I need to write code that would open dosbox (it's like cmd), pass 2 commands for it to execute, and I would like to have the dosbox running not in the background. Excuse me but I haven't done a similar thing before. Appreciate your help.